# Ktrain |my model giving good performance on train/val data during training but no on test data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-classification

Need some guidance.

I am training one model.I amm getting good training and validation accuracy (98%) but when i test the model on my test data then accury drops alot.

it drops to 80%.

any suggestion on how to improve performance on test data?

PS: My data is text (tweets only). and m only fine tuning a pretrained model on my data. and my using Ktrain library with Bert model

thanks.

**Update**

I tried Strathfield kfold(10) and score improved a bit. Jumped from 80 to 81.25%.)  Also I used weight decay with train test split (80-20) with weight decay of 0.01 but performance dropped to 75%.

Should I try Strathfield Kfold (10), shuffle= true, with weight decay = 0.01? or any other advise pls

Comment: Can you share more information regarding the data-set and the problem? 
Specifically, the number of classes/labels, whether they are balanced, if you are stratifying, etc.  
Also, what hyper-parameters are you using for fine-tuning BERT? 
This sounds like an over-fit but it would be good to have more information

Comment: @A.T.B Thanks for your reply..... Data is about misinformation problem ...its was imbalanced but I just added samples of low class in training data and shuffled (m not sure if I should do it or not)..I tried SMOTE but failed..I tried class weights and other techs to solve this imbalance issue....
I am using lr=0.00001 and now trying with Kfold (CV) and also used weight decay (0.01) for regularzition ...but still facing the same issue...

Comment: **update**

I tried Strathfield kfold(10) and score improved a bit. Jumped from 80 to 81.25%.)  Also I used weight decay with train test split (80-20) with weight decay of 0.01 but performance dropped to 75%.

Should I try Strathfield Kfold (10), shuffle= true, with weight decay = 0.01? or any other advise pls